# How to group by all variables except some and add a group id to every observation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set like this:

```
data(CO2, package = 'datasets')

##    Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake
## 1    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0
## 2    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4
## ... 
## 17   Qn3      Quebec nonchilled  250   40.3
## 18   Qn3      Quebec nonchilled  350   42.1
## ...
## 27   Qc1      Quebec    chilled  675   35.4
## 28   Qc1      Quebec    chilled 1000   38.7
## ...
## 36   Qc3      Quebec    chilled   95   15.1
## 37   Qc3      Quebec    chilled  175   21.0
## ...
## 47   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled  500   30.9
##  ...
## 53   Mn2 Mississippi nonchilled  350   31.8
## 54   Mn2 Mississippi nonchilled  500   32.4
## ...
## 62   Mn3 Mississippi nonchilled  675   28.1
## 63   Mn3 Mississippi nonchilled 1000   27.8
## ...
## 70   Mc1 Mississippi    chilled 1000   21.9
## 71   Mc2 Mississippi    chilled   95    7.7
## 72   Mc2 Mississippi    chilled  175   11.4
## ...
## 83   Mc3 Mississippi    chilled  675   18.9
## 84   Mc3 Mississippi    chilled 1000   19.9
```

- The observations shall be grouped according to the combination
  of **all variables except** `conc` and `uptake`. So I want to specify the 
  variables that I *don't* want to use for grouping
- I want to add a new variable `GroupID` to the data set, where all observations
  which belong to the same group have the same value of `GroupID`

I have found a working solution, however it is a behemoth:

```
library(dplyr)
CO2 %>% 
  mutate(GroupID=
         do.call( group_indices
                , c( list(.data=.)
                   , colnames(.) %>% 
                      setdiff(c('conc','uptake')) %>% 
                      as.name()
                   )
                )
         )

##    Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake GroupID
## 1    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0       1
## 2    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4       1
## ...
## 8    Qn2      Quebec nonchilled   95   13.6       2
## 9    Qn2      Quebec nonchilled  175   27.3       2
## ...
## 15   Qn3      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.2       3
## 16   Qn3      Quebec nonchilled  175   32.4       3
## ...
## 22   Qc1      Quebec    chilled   95   14.2       4
## 23   Qc1      Quebec    chilled  175   24.1       4
## ...
## 29   Qc2      Quebec    chilled   95    9.3       6
## 30   Qc2      Quebec    chilled  175   27.3       6
## ...
## 36   Qc3      Quebec    chilled   95   15.1       5
## 37   Qc3      Quebec    chilled  175   21.0       5
## ...
## 43   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled   95   10.6       9
## 44   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled  175   19.2       9
## ...
```

Is there an easier solution?

---

*Bonus:* It would be a blast if there were a solution which would use all variables *of the same type* (e.g. all factor variables) for grouping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `group_by_if` to group variables based on a condition. In this case, `is.factor` is to evaluate if a column is a factor. After that, `group_indices` can generate ID for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

CO2_2 <- CO2 %>%
  mutate(GroupID = CO2 %>%
           group_by_if(is.factor) %>%
           group_indices())
head(CO2_2)
#   Plant   Type  Treatment conc uptake GroupID
# 1   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0       1
# 2   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4       1
# 3   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  250   34.8       1
# 4   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  350   37.2       1
# 5   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  500   35.3       1
# 6   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  675   39.2       1
```

We can also use `group_by_at` to group the data frame based on column names.

```
CO2_3 <- CO2 %>%
  mutate(GroupID = CO2 %>%
           group_by_at(vars(-conc, -uptake)) %>%
           group_indices())
head(CO2_3)
#   Plant   Type  Treatment conc uptake GroupID
# 1   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0       1
# 2   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4       1
# 3   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  250   34.8       1
# 4   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  350   37.2       1
# 5   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  500   35.3       1
# 6   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  675   39.2       1
```

Comment: In my case I had not such a nice simple name like `CO2`, but my input resulted from some chained operations. In that case you can use The Dot:

`df_with_groupID <- df %>% ... %>% ... %>% ... %>% mutate(GroupID = group_by_if(., is.factor) %>% group_indices())`

Answer (score 3):

The `.GRP` from `data.table` can be used

```
library(data.table)
setDT(CO2)[, GroupID := .GRP, setdiff(names(CO2), c('conc','uptake'))]
```

Comment: This is good to know, `data.table` really can express this quite succinctly! For the sake of my readers' sanity, I will stick to dplyr for this analysis but it will certainly be useful in the future!

Answer (score 0):

using base r we can do something like this:

```
A=aggregate(cbind(conc,uptake)~.,CO2,length)[,"uptake"]#You can take either con or uptake 
transform(CO2,ID=rep(1:length(A),A))
   Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake ID
1    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0  1
2    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4  1
      :
8    Qn2      Quebec nonchilled   95   13.6  2
9    Qn2      Quebec nonchilled  175   27.3  2
      :
15   Qn3      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.2  3
16   Qn3      Quebec nonchilled  175   32.4  3
```

In one line format:

```
transform(CO2,fac=rep(d<-aggregate(cbind(conc,uptake)~.,CO2,length)[,"uptake"],d))
```